# Printing a malloc() declared array - A very short code that prints out of bounds?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, printf, bounds

Why does my program print an extra element, which looks like a memory location?

CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int *n=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    n[0]=1;
    n[1]=2;
    n[2]=3;
    for(i=0;n[i];i++)
        printf("\n%d\n",n[i]);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1

2

3

135153
```

Even when I replace(in line 2 of the main block)

```
int *n=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

with

```
int *n=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
```

the output is the same. What have I missed here?

EDIT: Ok, so from what I've been able to understand, you can only have a condition like this when you're running through a string and not just any array, since arrays allocated using malloc() don't have a terminating character like \0.

Comment: Because you are lucky, this is undefined behaviour. The condition in the for loop causes out of bounds.

Comment: so you can't check for n[i] like this using when malloc()?

Comment: @user3833914 No you can not because you don't know what is in the memory after your `n[i]` value.

Comment: `n[i]` is a value if value equals 0 the loops conditional is invalided and loop stops otherwise (i.e., if `n[i] != 0`) loop continues. In your case you are lucky you don't get a crash.

Comment: @WhozCraig:- I was about to comment the same thing!

Comment: @WhozCraig I firmly believe it too. "Lucky" was obviously a well intended irony :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly need to allocate `sizeof(int)*3`, or you will overwrite some other memory. Here, this has no effect, because your simple application has nothing else on the heap.

The other problem is the end condition in your for loop. `n[i]` means until there's by chance a 0 in the array. Your array is not 0-terminated, so it prints garbage. Use `for (i=0;i<3;i++)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your both versions of codes exhibit [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C.2B.2B) so output may be same or different or may crash or something else.

If you try to access beyond the memory successfully allocated, you may get any strange output.

```
int *n=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
if(n != NULL)
{
  n[0]=1;
  n[1]=2;  /* UB 1 */
  n[2]=3;  /* UB 2 */
  for(i=0;n[i];i++) /* UB 3 */
    printf("\n%d\n",n[i]); /* UB 4 */
}
```

With the change suggested by you, only UB1 and UB2 are fixed. UB3 and UB4 remain Undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your for loop:
replace it with: `for(i=0;i < 3;i++)`